# How to pass a non DB object from a template to a view outside the URL with Django ?

Tags: python, django

I'm fairly new to Django. I'm writing an app that displays articles using RSS. I want users to be able to react to any given article.

On the index, I display the latest articles dynamically (they are not stored in the DB). 
View :

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'publisher/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        feeds = feedparser.parse('http://www.foo.com/rss/news.xml')
        context['feeds'] = feeds
        return context
```

Template :

```
{% for entry in feeds.entries %}
    <li>
      <a target="_blank" href="{{entry.link}}">{{entry.title}}</a>
      <a href="{% url 'publisher:rss_react' entry %}">I want to react</a>
    </li>

{% endfor %}
```

This works so far. I have a link next to each of these articles that should call the RSSReactView and display the article title, abstract, and a form to react. I don't want the article to be saved anywhere if the reaction is not posted, and thus I don't want any parameter to be included in the URL of the reaction form.

URL :

```
app_name = 'publisher'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^new_rss/react/$', views.RSSReactView.as_view(), name='rss_react'),
]
```

View :

```
class RSSReactView(generic.CreateView):
    model = ReactionArticle
    form_class = ReactionForm
    template_name = 'publisher/react.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ReactView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        entry = self.kwargs['entry']
        context['entry'] = entry
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        pass
```

Template :

```
<h1>You are reacting to article {{ entry.title }}</h1>
<p>
  {{ entry.description }}
</p>
```

Of course, I get a NoReverseMatch error since the URL pattern isn't built to catch anything. 
Passing parameters from DB stored objects through the URL is straightforward, but how do I pass a context variable ('entry', in this case) as an object to another view without using the URL ?

NB : I'm aware of the solutions using sessions or posts, but I can't believe that's the only way of doing it.

Comment: I can't imagine what you expect. You want to pass an ID, but you don't want to use the URL, you don't want to use sessions, and you don't want to send it via POST. So what possible other options can there be?

Comment: Ok then, no other options. If I don't want to use the URL nor store it in the DB, what is my better option : POST or sessions ?